# Python compare two csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 csv files, i need to compare the data(for each name in 1.csv with complete array of name in 2.csv  and insert data in the below format to new output file.

1.csv

```
 ID   | Name | Fee

------|------|------

123   |abc   |110

234   |xyz  |160
```

2.csv (contains null values in Name)

```
----------
|Name |S1 |S2

abc   |60 |50

abc   |30 |40

xyz   |70 |90
```

ouput.csv

```
----------
|ID |S1  |S2  |Name |Fee

123 |    |    |abc  |

123 |60  |50  |     |110

123 |30  |40  |     |110

234 |    |    |xyz  |

234 |70  |90  |     |160
```

For initial start, thought of writing the output file with the values matched with 1.csv and then appending the ID and Names columns of 1.csv to the output file

```
reader1 = csv.reader(open('1.csv','rb'))
reader2 = csv.reader(open('2.csv','rb'))
writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv','wb'))
for row1 in reader1:
   for row2 in reader2:
       if row1[1] == row2[0]:
           data = [row1[1],row2[1],row2[2],row1[2]
           print data
           writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to go through the [tour] and earn your first badge. Unfortunately, SO is not a code writing service. Please show us what you've done and where you've gotten stuck. We'd be happy to help.

Comment: below is the code

Comment: No no no no no no no. It goes in your post, not in the comments.

Comment: Does your solution work? If not what does it do that you don't like?

Comment: well the loop is failing in 2 iteration. i can see only one iteration output.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to first read in `1.csv` into a Python dictionary which you can then use to look up values whilst you are reading `2.csv`. This avoids trying to read `1.csv` for every line in `2.csv`.

```
import csv

data_f1 = {}        # hold all of 1.csv in this dictionary

with open('1.csv', 'rb') as f_1:
    csv_f1 = csv.reader(f_1)
    header_f1 = next(csv_f1)

    for row in csv_f1:
        data_f1[row[1]] = [row[0], row[2]]

with open('2.csv', 'rb') as f_2, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_f2 = csv.reader(f_2)
    header_f2 = next(csv_f2)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['ID', 'S1', 'S2', 'Name', 'Fee'])

    for row in csv.reader(f_2):
        f1 = data_f1[row[0]]
        csv_output.writerow([f1[0], '', '', row[0], ''])
        csv_output.writerow([f1[0], row[1], row[2], f1[1]])
```

Giving you `output.csv` as follows:

```
ID,S1,S2,Name,Fee
123,,,abc,
123,60,50,110
123,,,abc,
123,30,40,110
234,,,xyz,
234,70,90,160
```

The reason your approach is failing to work a second time is that you would need to start reading the file from the top each time through the loop. Currently it will simply read to the end and then give you no more lines the second time you try. You could either close and reopen the file, or move the file pointer back to the start using `seek()`, but better still is to avoid repeatedly re-reading files, and store all the values you need in a Python dictionary. Try adding `print data_f1` and you can see what is stored.